# MATLAB plot with sorted order

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two vectors in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), say:

```
x = [1 20 3 7 10]
```

and

```
y = [2 51 1 9 18]
```

How can I plot `y` vs K where `x` has sorted value order (1 3 7 10 20) with their respective `y` values like the following?

```
x = [1 3 7 10 20]
y = [2 1 9 18 51]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call sort with a second output argument.

```
x = [1 20 3 7 10]  
y = [2 51 1 9 18]  

[xsorted, I] = sort(x)
ysorted = y(I)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XY = sortrows([x ; y]');

plot(XY(:,1), XY(:,2));
```

Concatenate the matrices, transpose them and then you can use sortrows to order by X